# Algebraic topology, Dynamical systems

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, fundamental-group

Let $T^2$ be a 2-torus and $f:T^2\rightarrow T^2$ a smooth map. Let $f_*:\pi_1(T^2)\rightarrow\pi_1(T^2)$ be the induced map on the fundamental group $\pi_1$. If $f_*$ has no eigenvalue greater than 1, then all balls of $T^2$ have subexponential growth by $ f $. Why?

Comment: What makes you think this is true? Also what do you mean by a ball having subexponential growth?

Comment: This statement is in a paper. Let $B\subset T^2$ be a ball, $B$ have subexponential growth by $f$ If $Vol(f^n(B))<\lambda^nVol(B)$, $\forall\lambda>1$.

Comment: But the measure is finite.

Comment: "This statement is in a paper." Cite?

Comment: This statement is in the paper [M.Brin, D. Burago, S Ivanov. ON PARTIALLY HYPERBOLIC DIFFEOMORPHISSMS OF 3-MANIFOLDS WITH COMMUTATIVE FUNDAMENTAL GROUP.] in the proposition 2.1

Comment: Vol is the riemannian volume, as $T ^ 2$ is compact volume is finite

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the paper of R. Bowen: ENTROPY FOR GROUP ENDOMORPHISMS AND
HOMOGENEOUS SPACES (Transactions of the AMS, 1971)